# Is it correct to say "as any human" meaning "as all humans"?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if it's correct to say *as any human* meaning *as all humans*? For example:

> As any human, I've also made mistakes.

What I'm trying to say is that all people have made mistaks, and I'm no exception.

Comment: This strikes me as the kind of sentence you get if you replace *part* of a good idiomatic sentence (like “I make as many mistakes as any human”) without making sure that the other parts still fit the new part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As any human" doesn't sound quite right in that context. And "also" is redundant, I think.

You **could** say, "As any human does, I make mistakes" or "I make mistakes as any human does." But we would usually just say 'anyone' not 'any human'.

Your sentence sounds like a mixture of two common expressions:

*Everyone makes mistakes.

I'm only human.*

It might be more idiomatic to say,

*I make mistakes, the same as everyone else.*
or
*I'm only human. I make mistakes.*

In those examples the present tense seems slightly more natural to me than the past tense, though you could say,

*I've made mistakes. Who hasn't?*

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you tell me if it's grammatically correct to say "as anyone I've made mistakes"?

Comment: "Like anyone [else], I've made mistakes" would be better.